# How to access static resources from thymeleaf javascript inline

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot project where I need to access a `.png` image file located in my `static/images` directory from a javascript code. I am using thymeleaf. I am using `th:inline="javascript"` from an html file like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    ...
       src: "<location of the image file>"
    ...
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

The png file is in `src/main/resources/static/images` directory and the javascript program is in an html file in `src/main/resources/templates` directory. I know I can use it using absolute path, but it will be not same when this will go in production, so I have to change it again. Thymeleaf has `th:src` to load static file from a context-based path, but it works only from html tags, is there anything similar for javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same standard URL syntax in inlined expressions as you do in regular Thymeleaf expressions.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
let src = /*[[@{/path/to/image.png}]]*/ null;
/*]]>*/
</script>
```